# function not called in escaping closure

Tags: ios, swift

I start learning MVVM and I decided to refactor my code with MVVM.
In ViewModel I have function which fetch *director* value:

```
 func loadDirector(id: Int, completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    homeRepository.getDirector(id: id){ (creditReponse) -> (Void) in
        creditReponse?.crew.forEach({ singleValue in
            if singleValue.knownForDepartment == .directing {
                self.directorName = singleValue.name 
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Function *getDirector* is from Repository where I am fetching data from URL.

```
func getDirector(id:Int, _ completed: @escaping (CreditsResponse?) -> (Void)) {
    movieServiceAPI.fetchData(from: NetworkData.directorUrl(id: id).value, by: completed)
}
```

View part where I am calling *loadDirector* :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let movie = homeViewModel.movieList[indexPath.row]
    homeViewModel.loadDirector(id: movie.id, completed: {

        self.changeVC(movie: movie, director: (self.homeViewModel.directorName), groups: self.homeViewModel.setupGenres(groups: movie.genreIds), movieIndex: indexPath.row)
        
    })

  }
```

Problem is when I click on cell in my tableview, function changeVC is not called (it doesnt show any error, function is just not called). *loadDirector* function firstly only had *id* parameter and then problem was that *directorName* wasnt updated on time (second cell click had first cell click *director* value). For that reason I added *escaping* closure so I can change my VC when *director* value is updated, but I am having problem with that. Where am I making mistake?

Comment: In your `loadDirector(id:completed:)` what is the point of `completed`? You never call it.